# Calculating a rolling weighted sum without a for loop in python/numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I recently asked the question: [NumPy convolve method has slight variance between equivalent for loop method for Volume Weighted Average Price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75192220/numpy-convolve-method-has-slight-variance-between-equivalent-for-loop-method-for)

Trying to use `np.convolve` was significantly faster than a standard for loop to calculate a rolling VWAP metric, but was providing an incorrect calculation as it was leaving off the last item in the array.

Is there a methodology to do a rolling weighted sum without a for loop?

## What I've tried:

### Using standard `for` loop (slow)

```py
def calc_vwap_1(price, volume, period_lookback):
    """
    Calculates the volume-weighted average price (VWAP) for a given period of time.
    The VWAP is calculated by taking the sum of the product of each price and volume over a given period, 
    and dividing by the sum of the volume over that period.
    
    Parameters:
        price (numpy.ndarray): A list or array of prices.
        volume (numpy.ndarray): A list or array of volumes, corresponding to the prices.
        period_lookback (int): The number of days to look back when calculating VWAP.
        
    Returns:
        numpy.ndarray: An array of VWAP values, one for each day in the input period.
    """
    vwap = np.zeros(len(price))
    for i in range(period_lookback, len(price)):
        lb = i - period_lookback  # lower bound
        ub = i + 1  # upper bound
        volume_sum = volume[lb:ub].sum()
        if volume_sum > 0:
            vwap[i] = (price[lb:ub] * volume[lb:ub]).sum() / volume_sum
        else:
            vwap[i] = np.nan
    return vwap
```

### Using `np.convolve` in `same` mode

```
def calc_vwap_2(price, volume, period_lookback):
    price_volume = price * volume
    # Use convolve to get the rolling sum of product of price and volume
    price_volume_conv = np.convolve(price_volume, np.ones(period_lookback), mode='same')[period_lookback-1:]
    # Use convolve to get the rolling sum of volume
    volume_conv = np.convolve(volume, np.ones(period_lookback), mode='same')[period_lookback-1:]
    # Create a mask to check if the volume sum is greater than 0
    mask = volume_conv > 0
    # Initialize the vwap array
    vwap = np.zeros(len(price))
    # Use the mask to check if volume sum is greater than zero, if it is, proceed with the division and store the result in vwap array, otherwise store NaN
    vwap[period_lookback-1:] = np.where(mask, price_volume_conv / volume_conv, np.nan)
    return vwap
```

### Using `np.convolve` in `valid` mode

```
def calc_vwap_3(price, volume, period_lookback):
    # Calculate product of price and volume
    price_volume = price * volume
    # Use convolve to get the rolling sum of product of price and volume and volume array
    price_volume_conv = np.convolve(price_volume, np.ones(period_lookback), mode='valid')
    # Use convolve to get the rolling sum of volume
    volume_conv = np.convolve(volume, np.ones(period_lookback), mode='valid')
    # Create a mask to check if the volume sum is greater than 0
    mask = volume_conv > 0
    # Initialize the vwap array
    vwap = np.zeros(len(price))
    # Use the mask to check if volume sum is greater than zero, if it is, proceed with the division and store the result in vwap array, otherwise store NaN
    vwap[period_lookback-1:] = np.where(mask, price_volume_conv / volume_conv, np.nan)
    return vwap
```

### Using `np.cumsum` (sorry mom) with slicing

```
def calc_vwap_4(price, volume, period_lookback):
    price_volume = price * volume
    # Use cumsum to get the rolling sum of product of price and volume
    price_volume_cumsum = np.cumsum(price_volume)[period_lookback-1:]
    # Use cumsum to get the rolling sum of volume
    volume_cumsum = np.cumsum(volume)[period_lookback-1:]
    # Create a mask to check if the volume sum is greater than 0
    mask = volume_cumsum > 0
    # Initialize the vwap array
    vwap = np.zeros(len(price))
    # Use the mask to check if volume sum is greater than zero, if it is, proceed with the division and store the result in vwap array, otherwise store NaN
    vwap[period_lookback-1:] = np.where(mask, price_volume_cumsum / volume_cumsum, np.nan)
    return vwap
```

### Using `np.reduceat`

```
def calc_vwap_5(price, volume, period_lookback):
    price_volume = price * volume
    # Use reduceat to get the rolling sum of product of price and volume
    price_volume_cumsum = np.add.reduceat(price_volume, np.arange(0, len(price), period_lookback))[period_lookback-1:]
    # Use reduceat to get the rolling sum of volume
    volume_cumsum = np.add.reduceat(volume, np.arange(0, len(price), period_lookback))[period_lookback-1:]
    # Create a mask to check if the volume sum is greater than 0
    mask = volume_cumsum > 0
    # Initialize the vwap array
    vwap = np.zeros(len(price))
    # Use the mask to check if volume sum is greater than zero, if it is, proceed with the division and store the result in vwap array, otherwise store NaN
    vwap[period_lookback-1:] = np.where(mask, price_volume_cumsum / volume_cumsum, np.nan)
    return vwap
```

### Using `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`

```
def calc_vwap_6(price, volume, period_lookback):
    price_volume = price * volume
    price_volume_strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(price_volume, shape=(len(price)-period_lookback+1, period_lookback), strides=(price_volume.strides[0], price_volume.strides[0]))
    volume_strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(volume, shape=(len(price)-period_lookback+1, period_lookback), strides=(volume.strides[0], volume.strides[0]))
    price_volume_sum = price_volume_strided.sum(axis=1)
    volume_sum = volume_strided.sum(axis=1)
    mask = volume_sum > 0
    vwap = np.zeros(len(price))
    vwap[period_lookback-1:] = np.where(mask, price_volume_sum / volume_sum, np.nan)
    return vwap
```

### Test Data

```
import numpy as np

price = np.random.random(10000)
volume = np.random.random(10000)
print(calc_vwap(price, volume, 100))
print()
print(calc_vwap_1(price, volume, 100))
print()
print(calc_vwap_2(price, volume, 100))
print()
print(calc_vwap_3(price, volume, 100))
print()
print(calc_vwap_4(price, volume, 100))
print()
print(calc_vwap_5(price, volume, 100))
print()
print(calc_vwap_6(price, volume, 100))
print()
```

### Results

```
vwap_1 -> [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.47375965 0.47762679 0.48448903] # CORRECT CALCULATION

vwap_2 -> [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.53108759 0.51933363 0.51360848]

vwap_3 -> [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.49834202 0.4984141  0.49845759]

vwap_4 -> [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.49834202 0.4984141  0.49845759]

vwap_5 -> [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.48040529 0.48040529 0.48040529]

vwap_6 -> [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.47027032 0.48009596 0.48040529]
```

Comment: I think the problem might be the origin of the kernel. Pretty sure that `numpy.convolve()` uses the center of the kernel as the origin, while I can see that in your reference implementation the right side of the kernel is the origin. See [`scipy.ndimage.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html) for a convolution implementation that allows for a change of origin.

Comment: @KellyBundy I just used randomly generated data from `np.random`, but I've pasted the calls if you want to try.

Comment: In the convolve solutions, why do you use a shorter period size? I.e., *why* are you still leaving one off? Just don't do that?

Comment: I'm not intending to, but I don't where in the syntax I'm shortening the period size? or leaving one off?

Comment: Version 1 uses period_lookback+1 elements each time, but versions 2 and 3 only use period_lookback elements.

Comment: I see. I tried changing these values at one point, but always got `ValueError` for having mishaped arrays.

I needed to increment period_lookback for the `price_volume_conv` and `volume_conv` and then in the check, needed the slicing to be at `vwap[period_lookback:]` or decremented compared the previous version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done as follows:

**Using np.convolve in same mode**

```
def calc_vwap_2(price, volume, period_lookback):
   price_volume = price * volume
   # Use convolve to get the rolling sum of product of price and volume
   if period_lookback%2 == 0:
       st = period_lookback//2
       en = -period_lookback//2
   else:
       st = period_lookback//2 + 1
       en = -period_lookback//2 + 1
   price_volume_conv = np.convolve(price_volume, np.ones(period_lookback+1), mode='same')[st:en]
   # Use convolve to get the rolling sum of volume
   volume_conv = np.convolve(volume, np.ones(period_lookback+1), mode='same')[st:en]
   # Create a mask to check if the volume sum is greater than 0
   mask = volume_conv > 0
   # Initialize the vwap array
   vwap = np.zeros(len(price))
   # Use the mask to check if volume sum is greater than zero, if it is, proceed with the division and store the result in vwap array, otherwise store NaN
   vwap[period_lookback:] = np.where(mask, price_volume_conv / volume_conv, np.nan)
   return vwap

 # 1.11 ms ± 26.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Using np.convolve in valid mode**

```
def calc_vwap_3(price, volume, period_lookback):
    # Calculate product of price and volume
    price_volume = price * volume
    # Use convolve to get the rolling sum of product of price and volume and volume array
    price_volume_conv = np.convolve(price_volume, np.ones(period_lookback+1), mode='valid')
    # Use convolve to get the rolling sum of volume
    volume_conv = np.convolve(volume, np.ones(period_lookback+1), mode='valid')
    # Create a mask to check if the volume sum is greater than 0
    mask = volume_conv > 0
    # Initialize the vwap array
    vwap = np.zeros(len(price))
    # Use the mask to check if volume sum is greater than zero, if it is, proceed with the division and store the result in vwap array, otherwise store NaN
    vwap[period_lookback:] = np.where(mask, price_volume_conv/volume_conv, np.nan)
    return vwap

# 1.22 ms ± 17.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Using np.ufunc.reduceat**

```
def calc_vwap_5(price, volume, period_lookback):
    price_volume = price * volume
    # Use reduceat to get the rolling sum of product of price and volume
    
    indices = np.arange(0,len(price)+1)
    isz = indices.itemsize
    indx = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(indices, shape=(len(price)-period_lookback, 2), strides=(isz, (period_lookback+1)*isz))
    price_volume_cumsum = np.add.reduceat(price_volume, indx.ravel()[:-1])[::2]
    # Use reduceat to get the rolling sum of volume
    volume_cumsum = np.add.reduceat(volume, indx.ravel()[:-1])[::2]
    # Create a mask to check if the volume sum is greater than 0
    mask = volume_cumsum > 0
    # Initialize the vwap array
    vwap = np.zeros(len(price))
    # Use the mask to check if volume sum is greater than zero, if it is, proceed with the division and store the result in vwap array, otherwise store NaN
    vwap[period_lookback:] = np.where(mask, price_volume_cumsum / volume_cumsum, np.nan)
    return vwap
# 1.64 ms ± 36.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Using np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided**

```
def calc_vwap_6(price, volume, period_lookback):
    price_volume = price * volume
    s = price_volume.itemsize
    price_volume_strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(price_volume, shape=(len(price)-period_lookback, period_lookback+1), strides=(s, s))
    vs = volume.itemsize
    volume_strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(volume, shape=(len(price)-period_lookback, period_lookback+1), strides=(vs, vs))
    price_volume_sum = price_volume_strided.sum(axis=1)
    volume_sum = volume_strided.sum(axis=1)
    mask = volume_sum > 0
    vwap = np.zeros(len(price))
    vwap[period_lookback:] = np.where(mask, price_volume_sum / volume_sum, np.nan)
    return vwap

# 1.09 ms ± 46.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Test Data**

```
price = np.random.random(10)
volume = np.random.random(10)

print(calc_vwap_1(price, volume, 2))
print(calc_vwap_2(price, volume, 2))
print(calc_vwap_3(price, volume, 2))
# print(calc_vwap_4(price, volume, 2))
print(calc_vwap_5(price, volume, 2))
print(calc_vwap_6(price, volume, 2))
```

**Results**

```
vwap_1 ->[0.         0.         0.42407022 0.30592959 0.40199312 0.62537516
 0.65380957 0.63246025 0.44962312 0.57632784]
vwap_2 ->[0.         0.         0.42407022 0.30592959 0.40199312 0.62537516
 0.65380957 0.63246025 0.44962312 0.57632784]
vwap_3 ->[0.         0.         0.42407022 0.30592959 0.40199312 0.62537516
 0.65380957 0.63246025 0.44962312 0.57632784]
vwap_5 ->[0.         0.         0.42407022 0.30592959 0.40199312 0.62537516
 0.65380957 0.63246025 0.44962312 0.57632784]
vwap_6 ->[0.         0.         0.42407022 0.30592959 0.40199312 0.62537516
 0.65380957 0.63246025 0.44962312 0.57632784]
```

At the end of each function, I have mentioned the timing details which I have obtained on 10000 random numbers and period lookback was 100, as per OP.

Comment: Why can't we do it with cumsum? Store it in `cs`, then do `cs[period_lookback+1:] - cs[:-period_lookback-1]`, no?

Comment: Yes maybe, this didn't cross my mind. thanks

Comment: Btw it would be nice to see runtimes. I'd use sizes 10000 and 100 as in the question. I imagine cumsum and subtraction might be faster than convolution.

Comment: Using `def one_convolve(a, width):`
    `cs = np.pad(a, (1, 0), "constant").cumsum()`
    `return cs[width:] - cs[:-width]` instead of `np.convolve` in `calc_vwap_3` seems to make it ~2.5 times faster (for sizes 10000 and 100).